# Как продолжить выполнение цикла, если словил исключение?

Tags: c#

Имеется список футболистов и уровень их мастерства. В блоке try я создаю цикл и проверяю условие. Если уровень футболиста меньше 20, то срабатывает исключение в блоке catch. Но у меня бывает, что не у одного футболиста уровень мастерства меньше 20. Как мне сделать так, чтобы проверял всех игроков, у которых уровень мастерства меньше 20, а потом уже попасть в блок catch?

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < FirstTeam.players.Count ; i++)
    {
        if (FirstTeam.players[i].SkillLevel < 20) 
        {
            throw new Exception(FirstTeam.players[i].Sername);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Ну копите инфу в список и кидайте исключение после окончания цикла, если этот список получился не пустой. А вообще я не понимаю зачем вам тогда исключение кидать, если вы не хотите, чтобы оно кидалось и всё-равно его тут же ловите получается после кидания )

Comment: Инвертируйте условие и если оно выполняется - добавляйте в новую коллекцию, если не выполняется - то ничего не делайте, пускай цикл дальше идёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое что тут можно сделать — инвертировать вложенность:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FirstTeam.players.Count ; i++)
{
    try
    {
        if (FirstTeam.players[i].SkillLevel < 20) 
        {
            throw new Exception(FirstTeam.players[i].Sername);
        }
    }    
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как инвертировать вложенность, я новенький в c#, можете подсказать кодом?

Comment: я и показал, вложил `try` в `for` у Вас было наоборот. таким образом цикл не прервется а все ошибки будут обработаны

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я если честно и думал, что for не там стоит где нужно, в данном случае. Ещё недопонимаю много вещей.

Comment: Если Вы начинающий программист — недопонимать нормально, если еще что-то осталось касательно этого вопроса можете уточнить тут в комментариях.

Comment: Можете тогда ещё подсказать. Как мне число 20 (уровень мастерства меньше 20) задать в основной программе? То есть создать переменную типа int с именем MinSkillLevel и присвоить значение 20, но чтобы название я писал MinSkillLevel, а не число. Пример: FirstTeam.players[i].SkillLevel < MinSkillLevel. Да, Этот код, с которым Вы мне помогли реализован в другом классе, а не в основной программе. То есть мне нужно, чтобы он увидел из основного класса название этой переменной (MinSkillLevel) в классе игра.

Comment: Все зависит от того что из себя представляет программа, в любом случае это делается либо через константу, либо переменную (если значение нужно менять) в данный цикл можно закидывать через параметр метода, а можно через глобальный объект settings (создаете любой класс где будут настройки общие для всего кода, делаете его [синглтоном](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/2.3.php) и можете обращаться к нему в любом месте программы. Главное — не спешите, лучше напишите как получается, позже будете писать как нужно — все и сразу получается у единиц.